# How to put a range in Sparql

Tags: range, sparql

I have a query which return a lot of rows, so much in fact that the server can't cope. Now I have put a limit on it to make it work, but I need the remainder of the results.

Is there a function like a range so I can get all of the results from where I have limited it?

I was thinking of somehow putting a counter in and filtering on that? Is this a possibility?

I am completely new to sparql and only have little experience with it.

Comment: 1. Provide current query + minimal data + expected result. 2. SPARQL Limit + Offset allows for pagination

Comment: I suggest you start with the [SPARQL documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/), particularly the [part about `ORDER BY`, `OFFSET`, and `LIMIT`](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#solutionModifiers)

Comment: Thank you guys! It worked by using order by limit and offset indeed.